Ubuntu server installation stuck at "configuring apt"
I am turning a laptop I don't need into an ubuntu server, but when I get to the installing system section the installation gets stuck at "configuring apt". I have been waiting for 2 hours to see if the problem was my laptop speed, and I don't think it is actually installing anything. I have also tried installating with no internet connection to no success. Does anybody have a solution/workabout to this problem?

After tinkering for a while, I found that part of my hard drive is broken. It still works but I can only use half of the storage, and the installer wanted to install on the parts of the hard drive I can't use, so it went into a loop. I fixed it by using a partition the size of half the hard drive as the one ubuntu uses.
